# Message from devtools panel to contents script when devtools opened in separate window

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome extension and I need send message from devtools panel which I created to content script. I've already done this:

**devtools.js**

```
$(function () {
    inputField.trigger('focus')
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {content: 'content'})
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
            if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(message.pageHTML)) {
                pageHTML = message.pageHTML
            }
        })
    })

})
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionID, {pageHTML: $('html').html()});
```

But it works only when devtools is pinned to any tab side, to the right, for example.
When I open devtools as separate window, script loses its connection with content script and I have error:

> Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

So how do I fix this?

Comment: Use [chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_inspectedWindow#method-eval) with `useContentScriptContext: true` to invoke some global function in your content script directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the id of the inspected window with [chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.tabId](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/devtools_inspectedWindow/#property-tabId).

**devtools.js**

```
$(function () {
    inputField.trigger('focus')
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.tabId, {content: 'content'})
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
        if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(message.pageHTML)) {
            pageHTML = message.pageHTML
        }
    })
})
```

*The sendMessage accepts a response handler, with this you could maybe remove the listener which you register just after sending the message. [more info](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#event-onMessage)*