# Chrome extensions SendMessage - Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have the following code in my Content script :

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: "Start" }, (response) => {
.......
});
```

This message is sent to my js "file.js"
This file is instantiated in my html ("Panel.html") of my previously created tab in my DevTools.js with this code

```js
chrome.devtools.panels.create("BUILDER/web inspector",
null,
"Panel.html",
null
);
```

If I don't enter the tab created on the chrome inspector then I get the error in question on console.

As soon as I access the tab, when the file "file.js" is instantiated then I no longer receive the error on console:

> SendMessage - Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not
> exist

How can I do to avoid seeing the error in the console?

**EDIT**

I tried putting the SendMessage on my "file.js" and the OnMessage on the Content script I don't get any response

"file.js" ->

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ from:"VariableGrid.js", message: "richiestaAvvio" }, (response) => {
   //....
});
```

ContentScript.js ->

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    
    //...
    
    });
```

**EDIT**

I try the chrome.tabs.sendMessage but array tabs is empty

```js
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
  });
});
```

Comment: You can't send a message to an inactive panel because its scripts don't run yet. Depending on the eventual action your extension wants to perform, you may want to reverse the direction: your panel script will send a message to the content script's onMessage.

Comment: But if I invert it doesn't work

I tried putting the SendMessage on my "file.js" and the OnMessage on the Content script
I don't get any response @wOxxOm

Comment: I also tried putting OnMessage on the Background script
I correctly receive the call of my "file.js", then I try to do a SendMessage to contact the Content script but nothing

Comment: Add the new code to your question.

Comment: I added code, thanks

Comment: To send to a content script you need chrome.tabs.sendMessage with a tab id, [more info](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: I try the chrome.tabs.sendMessage but array tabs is empty, I added the code

Comment: I forgot to say, use chrome.tabs.sendMessage(chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.tabId, ....

Comment: thanks, it worked! post it as an answer @wOxxOm

Comment: Looks like an answer already exists: [Message from devtools panel to contents script when devtools opened in separate window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67685915)

Comment: However, the request for this question is different from the question for that link.

The final solution is the same.

If you think this question is not necessary, I delete it.
Thanks anyway @wOxxOm